# WebGrid filtering in ASP 4.5 MVC5 - Best practice

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, filtering, webgrid

I'm quite new to asp .net and I'm working with a WebGrid in MVC5 and I've created the folowing code in my strongly typed view:

```
  @{
      var grid = new WebGrid(Model.CustomerArticles, defaultSort: "Name");
   }

   @grid.GetHtml(columns: new[]{
      grid.Column("ArticleNr", "ArtikelNr"),
      grid.Column("Name", "Namn"),
      grid.Column("Category", "Kategori"), 
      grid.Column("CustomerArticleNr", "Kundens artikelNr"),
      grid.Column("InventoryCount", "Inventerat antal"),
      grid.Column("WasSyncronized", "Synkroniserades"),
      grid.Column(
        header: "Action", 
        format: @<text> @Html.ActionLink("Ta bort", "RemoveArticle", "Article", new { id = Model.SelectedID, articleId = item.ID }, null) </text>)
})
```

It's working fine and it's currently possible to filter by clicking the columns but I wonder if there is any simple solutions to filtering it futher? Like for example as the aspx gridview: http://csharpdotnetfreak.blogspot.com/2011/04/gridview-filterexpression-dropdownlist.html

Is there any equivalient or any other biolerplate implementations that aren't to complicated to implement?

The important thing with my solution is to make it simpler to work with the grid if there is a lot of data in it. Which I believe it not the current situation. So other suggetions to make is clearer is also welcome.